# Multer isn't passing in express put route

Tags: express, multer, multer-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to the file system with Multer. Please take a look at the relevant data in my route:

```
const
  ..
  multer = require('multer'),
  ..;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, req.params.id + file.originalname);
    }
  }),
  upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('profilePic');

router.put(
  '/:id',
  middleware.isLoggedIn,
  (req, res, next) => {

    User
      .findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id, req.body.user,
        (err, updatedUser) => {
          if (err) {
            return req.flash('error', err.message);
          }

          upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              eval(locus);
              return req.flash('error', err.message);
            }
            updatedUser = req.body.user;
            eval(locus);

            //redirect show page
            res.redirect('/dashboard/profile/' + req.params.id + '/edit');
          });
        });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

When I look at updatedUser the first thing I see is
`{ profilePic: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,....}` what am I doing wrong? It's not even updating the page now that I have the upload function in here. What I really want to do is get the destination to work on s3 but I need to get this to save first.

Comment: What r u using at front end side... I mean angular.js or something else???.

Comment: Nope. Just ejs, and jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a the most basic example of uploading an image using `multer`:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')
var app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // define where the file should be uploaded, else it will be uploaded to the system temp dir
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // ./uploads should be created beforehand
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  // define "filename", else a random name will be used for the uploaded file
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

// pic is the name of image field in the form
app.put('/profile', upload.single('pic'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file)
  res.send('Uploaded')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

And here is an example `curl` command to upload an image from the file system to the above app:

```
curl -X PUT -F 'pic=@/projects/eg/foto.png' localhost:3000/profile
```

Make sure the example works fine, to ensure you understand how `multer` handles file uploads, and that the issue is not with `multer`.

That said and done, `User.findByIdAndUpdate` seems to be storing the image data as a base64 encoded string somewhere; I have no idea what `User.findByIdAndUpdate` connects to. It is beyond the domain of `multer`.

Someone on our Gitter channel (https://gitter.im/expressjs/express) might be able to suggest something. Join us there.

Comment: Sure, User.findByIdAndUpdate is mongoose. However, now that Im looking at this with fresh eyes I have an idea.

Comment: Whats the idea because Im trying to accomplish the same thing?